# Proxy for a protocol over TCP

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

My company is working with a private protocol over TCP between two servers and now they are asking if we can listen on this protocol and try to block some of its messages.

I was thinking of using [Simpleproxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simpleproxy/), but I'm not sure how to listen to the protocol with this and also I'm not sure how robust this implementation is.

Is there any implementation or a design I can use to do this?

the Idea is that I need be in the middle and between the server and the client and pass through/forward the messages except when I send a failure response to the server when the messages are not accepted due to some specific rules I have.

The server will be Linux.

Let's say there is server1 that will connect to server2, and my server will be named middle_server, so server1 will change its configuration and will be connected to me and then middle_server will send to server2, then middle_server will receive the response from server2 and send it back to server1 as depicted below,

```
server1 --ask--> middle_server --ask---> server2
server2 --response--> middle_server --response---> server2
```

Comment: What is the protocol? Design will depend largely on what it is.

Comment: it's something weird and private used by the our vendor and our server. part of it is XML.

Comment: Can you access the router?

Comment: No I don't have access to the router.

Comment: Are both servers in the intranet? is it allowed to sniff network traffic? Can you change the network settings of the servers?

Comment: Both are in a local network, the server will change the configuration and will be connecting to me instead of the destination, and I need to reroute the traffic to the destination and get the response back to it from our server

Comment: You need to write a server that implements the protocol both as a server and a client. You will talk to the client as server and talk to the server as a client. When you pass messages between them, you filter them according to your rules. You will need at least enough of an implementation of the protocol to identify message boundaries. Do you have a specification for the protocol? If not, you'll have to at least reverse engineer how its message boundaries work. This is a big job and should be done by a programmer with some server-side experience. Language can be C, python, javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any actual packages that can do what you want but you should be able to use iptables to block specific strings using the string module.  I'm not too sure how well this would work if the string happens to be broken up among multiple packets but you can give it a try.

[stackexchange question on filtering http requests using iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28851/iptables-to-block-https-websites)

Comment: This will work randomly and unpredictably, for precisely the reason you mentioned.

Comment: What about acting as a relay, so I receive from server1 then I change the source IP and send it if I want to pass through the message to server 2, and reject it if I want to based on my rules?

Comment: that's what you'd be doing with iptables however to do this accurately you would need to do as david schwartz said and reassemble the packets before trying to apply any filters to them.